# Color a voronoi diagram in MATLAB according to the color values of the initial points

Tags: matlab, colors, matlab-figure, voronoi

I have a matrix of points named `start_coord` containing their x and y coordinates, as well as a column denoting their classification (1-5). I.e. the first row looks like [75, 100, 4].

I've calculated a voronoi diagram of this data using the code below

`[vc_x, vc_y] = voronoi(start_coord(:,1), start_coord(:,2));`

How would I go about coloring the resulting polygons by the classification value of the point contained within each polygon, i.e. the third column in `start_coord`?

**EDIT**
For quick plotting of polygons by color reference the answer in the comments below, which helped inform this edit. For getting the voronoi polygons for thousands of points written to an array that can be saved as an image refer to this code:

```
new_map = zeros(sm_size(1), sm_size(2));
        start_coord = readmatrix(char(join([csv_path, '/', run_types(run), common_name_csv], "")));
        sc_size = size(start_coord);
        
        dt = delaunayTriangulation(start_coord(:,1:2));
        [V,R] = voronoiDiagram(dt);
                
        for i = 1:sc_size(1)
            A=V(R{i},:);
            B=A(any(~isinf(A),2),:); % omit points at infinity
            bw = poly2mask(B(:,1), B(:,2), sm_size(1), sm_size(2));
            new_map(bw == 1) = color_map(start_coord(i,3));
        end
```

`new_map` can then be saved as an array or converted to RGB and saved as an image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `voronoiDiagram` to get the polygons.

```matlab
dt = delaunayTriangulation(start_coord(:,1:2));
[V,R] = voronoiDiagram(dt);
```

Then R{i} will be the vertices of polygon from start_coord(i,:)
So set the color to start_coord(i,3)'s color and:

```matlab
A=V(R{i},:);
B=A(any(~isinf(A),2),:); % omit points at infinity
plot(polyshape(B));
```

The only hiccup there is that the vertices at infinity get chopped off. But maybe that will get you close enough to what you want. If you need to fill to the edge, check out the [VoronoiLimit](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/34428-voronoilimit-varargin) function (which I have not tested).

e.g.:

```matlab
X = [-1.5 3.2; 1.8 3.3; -3.7 1.5; -1.5 1.3; ...
0.8 1.2; 3.3 1.5; -4.0 -1.0;-2.3 -0.7; ...
0 -0.5; 2.0 -1.5; 3.7 -0.8; -3.5 -2.9; ...
-0.9 -3.9; 2.0 -3.5; 3.5 -2.25];

X(:,3) = [ 1 2 1 3 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3]';

ccode = ["red","green","blue"];

dt = delaunayTriangulation(X(:,1:2));
[V,R] = voronoiDiagram(dt);
figure
voronoi(X(:,1),X(:,2))
hold on
for i = 1:size(X,1)
    A=V(R{i},:);
    B=A(any(~isinf(A),2),:);
    if(size(B,1)>2)
        plot(polyshape(B),'FaceColor',ccode(X(i,3)));
    end
end
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for commenting! Your solution makes it so I can plot a single polygon, but not necessarily the entire voronoiDiagram. I've tried iterating over your code and plotting each i on the same figure, though that seems to time out atm. I also can't seem to find where to set the color in polyshape. Patch has something like this but requires different input.

Comment: Color with ` plot(polyshape(B),'FaceColor','green')` for example.

Comment: To plot multiple at a time, use `hold on`

Comment: I've added a full example of the details needed to make a whole plot.

Comment: @BryanCannon : I also found a function `VoronoiLimit` that makes useful vertices at the boundary rather than setting them all to infinity. I haven't tested that, though. Link added to the answer above.

Comment: Thanks again for the help! Your method definitely works, and is the easiest way to a visualisation. I had to adjust some things to account for the fact that I was working with thousands of polygons that wouldn't plot together without timing out. Code for plotting them all to an array to be saved as an image later is in the edit.